# access the rowlistview programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to change the alignment of the text in `ListView` programmatically instead of changing the xml file.

Here is my `row_listview.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowList" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip" 
    android:gravity="left" 
    android:textColor="#330033"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

And `activity_main.xml` has following `ListView` defined there

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" 
    android:background= "#FF6600">
 </ListView>
```

So in my `mainactivity.java` I am trying to change the alignment of the text in listview at runtime when user clicks a button on my activity

```
private ListView lv;
private TextView tvRowListView;
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_listview, sampleStringArray));
tvRowListView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRowList);
tvRowListView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

The last line above is however throwing nullpointerexception. I am not sure why. Can someone throw some ideas/solutions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your textViewRowList  exists for every item in that list, if you want to change it's properties you will need to do it in the `Adapter` in `getView` which means you will need to make a custom adapter

Comment: Thanks. i could get some more questions in the forum addressing the customer adaptor thing. I think I now know the the way out to my problem.